# Isogeny of elliptic curve over positive characteristic $p$ which does not come from characteristic $0$

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, arithmetic-geometry, elliptic-curves, characteristic-p

Let $K$ be quadratic imaginary field. Let $E$ be an elliptic curve which has CM over $R_K$
($R_K$ is ring of integers of $K$).

According to SIlverman's ''ADvanced topics in the arithmetic of elliptic curves'', p$129$, lemma $5.2$,

> Suppose $E$ is defined over some number field $L$. Let $P$ of $L$ at
> which $E$ has good reduction, and $ \tilde{E}$ be the reduction of $E$
> at $P$. Let $θ:End(E)→End( \tilde{E})$ be the natural map which takes
> an endomorphism to its reduction mod $P$.  Then, if $ \tilde{E}$ is
> supersingular(its endomorphism ring is isom to order in quaternion
> algebra), $θ$ is not always surjective.

My question is, what is an concrete example of $φ\in End({ \tilde E})$ which does not come from $End(E)$ ?
For example, let $L= \Bbb{Q}( \sqrt{-1})$ and $E/L:y^2=x^3＋x $.
Let $P$ be a prime ideal above $7$.
Then $ \tilde{E}/ \Bbb{F}_{49}:y^2=x^3+x$ is supersingular. I want to find concrete example of  $φ\in End({ \tilde E})$ which does not come from $End(E)$.

Comment: Frobenius       It doesn't commute with $[i]$.